# Is there a better way to serve and encode a large SQLAlchemy dataset from FastAPI?

Tags: json, api, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I want to return a large dataset using **FastAPI** `StreamingResponse` and in the repository/logic layer, after doing my query stuff, I'm returning the data in this way:

```py
for record in query.yield_per(DATA_RECORDS_LIMIT):
            yield record.to_entity()
```

I initially had some encoding issues (encoder method was missing, couldn't serialise a datetime etc...) and thanks to this https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/419#issuecomment-470077657 and this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/#using-the-jsonable_encoder I ended up with this final code in the web handler:

```py
...
results = get_data()

def _encoded_results():
        yield "["
        for idx, item in enumerate(results):
            if idx > 0:
                yield ","
            yield json.dumps(jsonable_encoder(item.dict()))
        yield "]"

return StreamingResponse(_encoded_results())
```

Now... before you ask: yes, **it works**, but I was wondering i**f all this is necessary or if there is a better way of doing that**. To add more context the record in the first snippet is a **SQLAlchemy** model instance and the `.to_entity()` transform it to a **Pydantic** data instance. In the second snippet I call `.dict()` on the pydantic class so I get a Python `dict` which can be passed through `jsonable_encoder` before being `.json.dumps(...)`.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one trying to use FastAPI to return/stream a very large dataset, so I'm wondering if there is anything builtin or a better way to do this. Thanks

**Note:** my main concern (in case I wasn't clear) it's about the fact that given a **Pydantic** entity I need to first call the `.dict()` method, then it needs to through `jsonable_encoder` and finally through `json.dumps`. I wish this transformation was implemented somewhere inside FastAPI and hidden from the web handler. TL/DR `_encoded_results` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the fact that you’re trying to stream JSON so you can’t benefit from all the goodies FastAPI has to offer. You don’t need to call `.dict() `, `jsonable_encoder` is able to parse Pydantic models, assuming individual items are models. The usual workflow is to declare the response model with the `response_model` parameter and FastAPI will do the parsing, validation etc. You could perhaps stream bytes or text and then massage the data on the client side but not sure if this viable option in your case.